# This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure

Tags: android

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Vulnerability   APK Version(s)  Past Due Date
TrustManager
You can find more information about TrustManager in this Google Help Center article.

227 February 24, 2021
To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your app to the Play Console and check back after five hours to make sure the warning is gone.

While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.

Comment: Can someone help me for this case, I had rejected by google for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy.

Comment: Without further information, we can only guess. Most likely you you either added or changed something that created a vulnerability, or a vulnerability was reported in one of your dependencies and you have not updated them.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede is this issue related thí email we received ? : " We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of your app bundles or APKs."

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) say apps targeting Android 11 will ignore that flag. If it's being ignored, it shouldn't be considered a vulnerability. But you never know with Google.

Comment: Sounds like it might be related to [this](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016?hl=en). The text you posted probably contained links; those would be helpful. But if you don't understand what those links are about, you should probably ask a more focused question about that.

Comment: How can we know exactly problem, since they only show the issue related to TrustManage? @KevinKrumwiede. we have fix with google by link : https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016?hl=en

Comment: I don't understand "we have fix with google by link". Are you saying that was the link in the email you got?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes, i followed all step they suggest on link in the email i got,  : https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016

Comment: I recommend asking a more focused question about that, including related code and all the steps you took.